# Lua: what scope do variables in "required" modules go to?

Tags: scope, lua

After spending the week learning Lua, I was a bit shocked to encounter this weird scenario, since I had previously imagined that the "require" command worked just like a #include in C/C++ (i.e., it's copy/pasted in by the preprocessor).

Obviously that's not the case.

Here's what stumped me:

```
-- a.lua
this_is_global = "I'm a global var!!"
require "b"
print(global_in_b) -- error??!! globals in b aren't truly global?

-- b.lua
print(this_is_global) -- prints "I'm a global var!"
-- so b can see globals from a
global_in_b = "Am I global too?"
```

For productivity reasons I've just been creating my own table to act as a scope in b, adding everything I want to access to that table, and then returning the table in b so that I can write:

```
-- a.lua
stuff_from_b = require "b"
print(stuff_from_b.global_in_b)  -- does what we want, in a weird way
```

I know I can also manually add stuff in b.lua to the _G table to force them to be global, but that feels ugly.

So my questions:

- What's exactly happening with "globals" in required files?  What table do they end up in if not _G?
- What're the commonly accepted ways of accessing scopes of required files?

Comment: `require` is just sugar for `loadfile('file')()` call

Comment: When you `load` or `loadstring` source code (which `dofile` does internally), it's given its own `global environment`. I believe you can manually load your file into a buffer and load it using `_G` but this only works in Lua 5.2+ if I recall correctly.

Comment: @hjpotter92, no it is not sugar for that: there is testing whether the module have already been loaded, searching for the module, saving the results in the loaded table, etc.

Comment: @andy What is the error message? It shouldn't error, it should at least print `nil` even if module scope and global scope were different (e.g. by using the deprecated `module` function, or by replacing `require` with a custom implementation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither `require` nor `dofile` are equivalent to `include`: both run code at run time, not textually add source code during compilation.

The globals that a required file sees are the same as the globals in the file that required it.

To avoid pollution and to allow privacy and hiding, it is good practice that Lua modules create and return a table with what they want to export to the external world. It is up to the designer of the module to decide what can be seen from the outside.

Comment: I think either the OP's example is wrong, or this statement is not entirely: `The globals that a required file sees are the same as the globals in the file that required it.` If b.lua global is truly global, then `global_in_b` should be printable in a.lua after require, unless OP is omiting some `local`